# Data grid style windows mobile c#

Tags: windows-mobile

I'm trying to style a column in my `DataGrid` so it would fit 100% to the width of screen.

I bind data to my grid with:

```
        DataTable dt = new LoadGenres().Load(strFullPathToMyFile).Tables[0];
        genreGrid.DataSource = dt;
```

LoadGenres uses the XML below to create a dataset:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<list>
<genre>Top 500</genre>
<genre>70s</genre>
<genre>80s</genre>
</list>
```

That works fine but on screen I get the image below:

[alt text http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/7054/20090306190547.png](http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/7054/20090306190547.png)

How can I get columns to fit the width of the grid?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

got it with

```
DataTable myTable = new DataTable();
        myTable = new LoadGenres().Load(strFullPathToMyFile).Tables[0];
        genreGrid.DataSource = myTable;
        DataGridTableStyle tableStyle = new DataGridTableStyle();
        tableStyle.MappingName = myTable.TableName.ToString();
        DataGridTextBoxColumn tbcName = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
        tbcName.Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width;
        tbcName.MappingName = myTable.Columns[0].ColumnName.ToString();
        //tbcName.HeaderText = myTable.Columns[0].ColumnName.ToString();
        tableStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(tbcName);
        genreGrid.TableStyles.Clear();
        genreGrid.TableStyles.Add(tableStyle);
```